# SDL icons do not support semi-transparency

Tags: c, icons, sdl, transparency

To set the icon for a settings window, I use this code:

```
SDL_WM_SetIcon(IMG_Load("settings.png"),NULL);
```

settings.png is a 32x32 PNG image with semi-transparency placed in the same folder as the executable. The problem is that the title bar looks like this:

[image: title bar]

In case you can't see the black on the screenshot above the first time you look, here's a zoomed version of it with an arrow showing an example of the parts that I'm talking about:

[image: zoom]

As you can see, at the places where there is supposed to be semi-transparency, there is black instead which makes it a bit ugly. I tried to take away the semi-transparency with IcoFx using "Insert new image" and then selecting "True Color (24 bits)" (which takes away the semi-transparency and replaces the image with what it would look like on a white background without changing parts that are totally transparent), but I still get the same result. I also tried reducing the size of the image to 16x16 but that makes it even worse. How do I fix this? If it's possible, I would prefer to keep the semi-transparency since the taskbar supports it just fine.

Comment: I don't see black, except for the text.

Comment: @Olaf I've edited to make it clear what black I'm talking about.